# how to override or substitute default django admin site template?

Tags: django, django-templates

**FIRST:**

I used django admin site as my website management system,but some features are not appropriate to me,so i decide to make my own,according to django docs,what i learned is that I can override `Templates` per app or model while i can extend `AdminSite` to build a brand new one.But,i have some problems playing around them,what i was trying to do were:

**1,article/admin.py** (one app of my project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from .models import Article,ArticleImage,Category

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = "Moonmoonbird administration"

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name="myadmin")
admin_site.register(Article)
```

**2,settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
    'django.contrib.messages', 
    'django.contrib.sessions', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig',(which docs suggest to do)
    'jwtauth',
    'navigation',
    'myadmin',
    'article',
)
```

**3,urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from jwtauth.views import obtain_jwt_token
from django.contrib.auth.admin import admin
from article.admin import admin_site
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'moonmoonbird.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'myadmin/',include(admin_site.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/',obtain_jwt_token.as_view())
)
```

When i access `example.com/admin` and `example.com/myadmin`,they are the same,both are the django admin site default implementation.I cannot see where i was doing wrong.

**SECOND:**

Lets say a use case(which i meet now),an article app of my project,which has  title,tag,and content attributes,I install it into admin site by doing this:

**article/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(ArticleImage)
```

and now i can manipulate CURD in admin site,but what i want is that i can edit my article content like SO do,that is using a [pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/checkout) editor for say(which actually i want to use) ,but i dont know how to do it.

**Question:**

**1, how can i make the FIRST workflow works?**

**2,how to do and what you suggest me to do to implement the SECOND case?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Think well if you really have to change the whole admin template. In majority of cases, you need several small changes. There are good properties in admin.ModelAdmin class for many useful customizations. It is even possible to override some parts of the admin template with your HTML template.

Read the [Django tutorial, Part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#enter-the-admin-site) for examples how to easily change Admin page functionality and look.

Can you tell what exactly you need to change in your admin page?

Comment: Hi,just like what i said in SECOND part,i already had an article edit page in admin site,but i want to change the way of editing the content of article to  the html editor other than the simple default way which is just typing plain word,i need some format,color etc  like SO does.BTW,the FIRST part is also not work,which i follow the docs.